# "someday" Vs "some day"

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase-usage

You should come by some day.

You should come by someday.

Is there a difference between these? Are both technically correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

> **You should come by someday.**

*Some day* means:

> a single day that is unknown or unspecified

Whereas *someday* means:

> refers to future events that will occur at an indefinite time

Therefore, *some day* would be appropriate.

Whereas, if you were referring to a specific time, e.g. next month, you would use *some day* as you are referring to a specific day next month, even if that day is unknown:

> **You should come by some day next month**